# Angle orientation for data defined label rotation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-3

It seems that angle orientation for data defined label rotation is different in QGIS 2 (anti-clockwise) and QGIS 3 (clockwise). I mean angle values that are stored in the defined field when modifying label orientation with the graphic tool of the label toolbar.
Is this intentional ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson) (a core developer for QGIS) in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/qgis/qgis3.0_api/issues/18):

> Label rotation is applied counter-clockwise, symbology rotation is clockwise.
>
> I'd like to alter the labelling behaviour so that rotation is applied clockwise to match symbol rotation.
>
> If we allow project breaks for 3.0, this should be an easy fix. If not, rotation would have to be upgraded with projects to 3.0 to reverse the label rotation angle.

---

So yes, it is intentional and the fix can be seen here:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/21a4ac4d3a747182c78224e23718bd09c6243d73

Comment: @sigeal - Most welcome! Hope it was helpful :)